# Cronos Pro: missing opticals?

Tags: fonts, pdftex

I am experimenting with the use of alternate fonts with LaTeX using pdfTeX (no XeTeX nor LuaTeX).

I have installed [FontPro](https://github.com/sebschub/FontPro/) with Adobe Reader's Minion & Myriad Pro, plus some Cronos Pro files I had; small family (no semibold) but with all optical sizes (text, capt, subh, disp). Before building, I have renamed my CronosPro files as required by the instructions. The installation seemed to work fine.

However, I get fatal errors when I try using the `CronosPro` package with the `slides` or `opticals` options.

Non-working example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[opticals]{CronosPro}

\begin{document}
\sffamily
\LARGE Text
\end{document}
```

This gives:

```
[...]
kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 0+573/600 --dpi 573
CronosPro-Subh-Base-ac
mktexpk: don't know how to create bitmap font for CronosPro-Subh-Base-ac.
mktexpk: perhaps CronosPro-Subh-Base-ac is missing from the map file.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.

!pdfTeX error: /usr/texbin/pdflatex (file CronosPro-Subh-Base-ac): Font
CronosPro-Subh-Base-ac at 573 not found
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Again, I *did* put a `CronosPro-Subh.otf` in the `otf` subfolder of FontPro before running `make all`. Any suggestions about what might be going on?

Comment: Why don't you simply use `xelatex`. Then you can use the otf font version directly. Put the files into your systems font directory and use: `\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{CronosPro-Regular}`

Comment: @Herbert : Thanks, I will look into it someday; right now I'm more interested in making this work.

Comment: @DG' : Yes, I did run `clean` before `makeall`, the last time. And yes, I did run `updmap-sys --enable Map=CronosPro.map` after `install`. In fact, I don't get any errors if I don't use `slides` nor `opticals`.

Comment: Does `CronosPro-Subh-Base-ac.tfm` exist? Is `CronosPro-Subh-Base-ac` mentioned in the map file?

Comment: @DG' I would not recommend installing fonts in `TEXMFHOME` or using `updmap`. It leads to all kinds of headaches later on. Installation should be to `TEXMFLOCAL` with `updmap-sys` unless a user simply has no other option. For testing, you can just have all of the font files in a single directory, including the map file, and use `\pdfmapfile{+CronosPro.map}` in the preamble of your test document, which should also be in the same directory.

Comment: @cfr : Yes, there is a `CronosPro-Subh-Base-ac.tfm` in `$TEXMFLOCAL/fonts/tfm/adobe/CronosPro`; and yes, `CronosPro-Subh-Base-ac` occurs twice in the file `$TEXMFLOCAL/fonts/map/dvips/CronosPro/CronosPro.map`.

Comment: What does `kpsewhich CronosPro-Subh-Base-ac.tfm` give? If it doesn't find it, run `mktexlsr $(kpsewhich --var TeXMFLOCAL))`. Is CronosPro-Subh-Base-ac listed in the files in `$(kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFSYSVAR)/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/`? (There are 3 files here, each ending in `.map`.) If not, you need to add the map file using `updmap-sys`.

Comment: @cfr : `kpsewhich` does find the tfm, but `CronosPro-Subh-Base-ac` (nor anything containing `Subh`, in fact) is not listed in any of those 3 map files. So how do I add it? So far, the only `updmap-sys` I've run (twice) was `updmap-sys --enable Map=CronosPro.map`. What else? Thanks a lot for your help; sorry to waste your time, I'm kind of a beginner at this.

Comment: Is `CronosPro-Subh-Base-ac` in `CronosPro.map`?

Comment: @cfr : yes, the line containing it is
`CronosPro-Subh-Base-ac CronosPro-Subh "CronosPro-Base-Encoding-ac ReEncodeFont" <[base-CronosPro-ac.enc <CronosPro-Subh.pfb`

Comment: When you add the map file, does it succeed? Which files does it say it has updated?

Comment: @cfr : I re-ran it, and this is the output:
`updmap will read the following updmap.cfg files (in precedence order):
  /usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg
  /usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg
updmap may write changes to the following updmap.cfg file:
  /usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg
/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg unchanged.  Map files not recreated.
updmap: Updating ls-R files.`

Comment: Does `/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg` include the map file?

Comment: It does. Actually, up until a few minutes ago, it also contained a nonexisting `CronosPro-Subh.map` – I added that via `updmap-sys` as one of the first thing I've tried. The weird thing is, after disabling that… everything works! I still have no clue about the reason why it didn't work before, but at least it's solved. Thanks everybody, @cfr in particular.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted ;).

Comment: @egreg er... OK. Give me a few minutes. (How did this get picked for answering-the-unanswered? Grrr.)

Comment: @egreg OK. Quite a few minutes...

Answer (score 6):

In order to use the new fonts, you need to ensure 2 things: that all of the files can be found, and that the fonts are correctly listed in the map files which TeX uses to match different bits of font information.

I recommend the following procedure if installing on TeX Live:

1. Test the fonts prior to installing them. To do this, put all the files in one directory (or make copies or symbolic links or whatever), create a test file using the new package and add `\pdfmapfile{+CronosPro.map}` before the `\usepackage...` command. Compile with pdfLaTeX and check that the results are as expected.

   - If this step fails, you are in trouble. Don't bother installing the fonts as moving them around won't make them suddenly work. Either the package is faulty or you made a mistake when converting the fonts or preparing the package for installation. Either way, go back to the `README` or installation instructions, and ask somebody for help if necessary.
2. Install into `TEXMFLOCAL` unless you do not have permission to do so. If you are not sure where this is, run `kpsewhich --var TEXMFLOCAL` to find out. On a Unix-ish system, with upstream's installer, this will be `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local` unless you changed the default.

   1. Put the files in the relevant places in `TEXMFLOCAL`. For example for type1 fonts from `vendor` packaged as `packagename`:

      - `.tfm` files in `fonts/tfm/vendor/packagename`
      - `.pfb` files in `fonts/type1/vendor/packagename`
      - `.map` files in `fonts/map/dvips/packagename`
      - `.fd` files and `.sty` files  [if applicable] in `tex/latex/packagename`
      - documentation in `doc/fonts/packagename` [if applicable]
      - `.vf` files in `fonts/vf/vendor/packagename` [if applicable]
      - `.enc` files in `fonts/enc/dvips/packagename` [if applicable]
      - `.afm` files in `fonts/afm/vendor/packagename` [if applicable]
      - source files in `source/fonts/packagename` [if applicable]
   2. Tell TeX about the new files by running `mktexlsr $(kpsewhich --var TeXMFLOCAL))`.
   3. Install the new map file fragment(s) by running `updmap-sys --enable Map=<mapfilename>.map` e.g. `updmap-sys --enable Map=CronosPro.map`.

      - ***Pay attention to the output.*** If the map files are not updated or `updmap-sys` can't find something, you need to diagnose and correct the problem. If you need help, be sure to include the errors and explain the steps you followed previously.
3. Now move your test file to a clean directory, delete the line which adds the map file manually, and rerun it. It should work as before.

   - If all is well, go to step 5.
   - If not, go to step 4.
4. Things to check/try:

   - If LaTeX complains that it cannot find a file, run `kpsewhich <filename>` to check. If it still can't find it, look for the file. Did you install it in the right place? If not, move it appropriately. After making any necessary adjustments, go to step 2.2. Check the file is found before progressing to step 2.3.
   - If LaTeX can't find a font at all (i.e. isn't complaining about a specific file, complete with extension, but just can't find a named font, which won't have an extension), get the value of `kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFSYSVAR` and look in `TEXMFSYSVAR/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/`. Do the files here include that font? If not, check the `.map` file you installed earlier. Is the font listed there? If not, something more serious is wrong. But if it is, try rerunning steps 2.2 and 2.3.
   - Do you have a directory name `.texliveYYYY` in your home directory, where `YYYY` is the edition of your TeX Live installation? For example, for TL 2014 on a GNU/Linux system this would be `/home/username/.texlive2014` if `username` is your user name. If you have such a directory, rename or delete it. (Only delete if you are 100% confident you have the correct directory.)
   - If it just isn't helping, running `updmap-sys --disable <mapfile>.map` and then `updmap-sys --enable Map=<mapfile>.map` may do the trick.
   - If it is now working, go to step 5.
   - If not, update your question or (if you are not the OP) ask a new question, detailing the results of the above steps. Be sure to include the output from step 2.3 and the specific errors you get when you try to compile your test file.
5. You are done!